# Open webcam settings dialog in Windows

Tags: windows-10, window

There is a webcam settings dialog in Windows which can be accessed inside Skype and some other apps, but I want to be able to open it directly. How can I open it directly? I have attached screenshot of dialog for reference.

[image]

Comment: Try Windows Key + R, and enter `ms-settings:privacy-webcam`

Comment: @DavidPostill It shows different dialog

Comment: Anybody?.......

Comment: This is really driving me crazy, I can access it Skype, I can write my own program to open it but I just want to open it within Windows...

Comment: @Fishcake How can you open it from your program. What's the API for it?

Comment: Added as an answer as too much for a comment

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know this thread is old but inspired from stevek_mcc's answer, I made a small script to launch the webcam settings dialog directly from Windows.

Github: [webcam-settings-dialog-windows](https://github.com/jpalbert/webcam-settings-dialog-windows)

Hope this could help someone!

Answer (score 35):

Thanks to [Fishcake's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1327095/132953), I was able to find a program that offers command-line access to the same [ISpecifyPropertyPages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ocidl/nn-ocidl-ispecifypropertypages) interface as AForge's [DisplayPropertyPage](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/1707ed1c-5a94-c3d8-c40b-8f7460e013cf.htm), and thus allows us to open the dialog: **ffmpeg**.

1. Download an [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org) Windows executable (e.g. from [zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)) and expand `bin\ffmpeg.exe` into a directory, e.g. `c:\utils`
2. Start a cmd prompt and change to that directory: `cd \utils`
3. Find the exact name of your device, either from Control Panel | Devices and Printers or by running ffmpeg:

   ```
   C:\utils>ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy -hide_banner
   [dshow @ 0000022fd7ac8440] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and audio devices)
   [dshow @ 0000022fd7ac8440]  "USB 2.0 CAMERA"
   ```
4. Run ffmpeg to show the dialog:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f dshow -show_video_device_dialog true -i video="USB 2.0 CAMERA"
   ```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: wish there was a way to feed it a set of sane defaults for gain/exposure etc.

Answer (score 10):

I have written a little program to do this and also to allow saving camera settings in different profiles.

http://faltinek.de/freestuff/CamooZ.zip

[image: CamooZ at work...]

Comment: It is never recommended to download software from a non-HTTPS connection, nor should a software link point to a downloadable file, but the software's webpage.  **It would be ill-advised for any user to click on the link in this answer**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And sorry about the downvotes. This site is not very friendly towards new users.

Comment: This would be really useful, and most would indeed just want to download the exe. But without a webpage, a digital signature and/or open source, many won't take the risk. I found the ffmpeg solution above only because it was open source: I could search the net for the function call. Maybe you could make the source available?

Comment: @VarunAgw Downvotes have nothing to do with being a new user, but the quality of the answer, and without some means of security verification for the suggested software, the software should never have been placed in an answer, which is why I down-voted.  IMHO, answers should never contain a link to a direct download, as it's a blatant, massive security risk and is therefore unacceptable, whether on Stack Exchange or any other forum.

Comment: @VarunAgw That's just common sense... any software developer should know to **(1)** Not post a non-HTTPS link to their software, and **(2)** not link directly to a direct download, but to the software's webpage.  There are trusted software development sites folks can host closed-source software on, GitHub being one of them.

Comment: @Falty +1 That looks great! Could you share what library or framework you where using to change the camera settings? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

News from CamooZ

this time properly posted in the OBS forum's tools section:

https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/camooz-tool-to-manage-and-save-and-restore-camera-settings.1271/

[image]

Comment: Links will change over time. It is not ok. You should post the full answer here and reference the source.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've managed to launch it without using an external program (e.g. Skype) was to use [AForge.Net](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/documentation.html)

Using AForge.Net, you can launch the property window by simply calling [DisplayPropertyPage](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/1707ed1c-5a94-c3d8-c40b-8f7460e013cf.htm) on a `VideoCaptureDevice`

```
videoCaptureDevice.DisplayPropertyPage(IntPtr.Zero);
```

Using AForge.Net might be overkill for just displaying the property page (I was using it already for some image manipulation) but you can view the source to see what it is doing under the hood. The DisplayPropertyPage method is in the class [VideoCaptureDevice.cs](https://github.com/andrewkirillov/AForge.NET/blob/master/Sources/Video.DirectShow/VideoCaptureDevice.cs)

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote my own simple script to quickly let me access the webcam settings for both my cameras, as the option to access the settings in most other applications are missing, except in Lync/Skype for Business (which hopefully nobody uses anymore.)

Anyway, I thought it'd be nice to share what I learnt.

#### Mixed *Winbatch* and *PowerShell* script

Its a mixed *Winbatch* and *PowerShell* script that enumerates all cameras and opens the Camera Property dialog for each of them using **ffmpeg**. Its mixed because I didn't want to modify my ExecutionPolicy-settings, where a regular **.ps1**-script would otherwise halt on confirming a ExecutionPolicy Change.

**OpenCameraSettings.cmd**

```winbatch
for /f "Usebackq Tokens=* Delims=" %%a in (`powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "(Get-PnpDevice).where{$_.Class -eq 'Camera'}.FriendlyName"`) do (
    ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -show_video_device_dialog true -i video="%%a"
)
```

##### Description

The script basically consists of a **Winbatch** ***For***-loop that enumerates Cameras using **PowerShell** and opens its properties using **ffmpeg**.

The **PowerShell**-part of the script also hides the terminal window that **ffmpeg** otherwise generates:

```powershell
powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "..."
```

The same **PowerShell** part of the script also enumerates all Camera devices:

```powershell
(Get-PnpDevice).where{$_.Class -eq 'Camera'}.FriendlyName
```

---

#### WinBatch Alternative (without any usage of PowerShell)

Uses **[PnPUtil](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil)** to query for Camera devices.
***[PnPUtil](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil)** comes built into newer versions of Windows and replaces Windows Device Console (**Devcon.exe**) that only comes with WDK, Visual Studio, and the Windows SDK for desktop apps.*

```winbatch
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "Usebackq Tokens=2 Delims=:" %%i in (`pnputil /enum-devices /Class Camera ^| find /i "Device Description"`) do (
    set cam=%%i
    rem trim double spaces
    set cam=!cam:  =!
    rem remove a space from the beginning of the string
    set cam=!cam:~1!
    ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -show_video_device_dialog true -i video="!cam!"
)
```

---

#### PowerShell alternative

*(will complain about ExecutionPolicy change depending on your configuration)*

Uses **[Get-PnpDevice](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pnpdevice/get-pnpdevice?view=windowsserver2019-ps)** from the PowerShell module [PnpDevice](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pnpdevice/?view=windowsserver2019-ps) to query for Camera devices.
*The PowerShell module [PnpDevice](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pnpdevice/?view=windowsserver2019-ps) comes with at least Windows Server 2012-2019 and Windows 10.*

```powershell
((Get-PnpDevice).Where{$_.Class -eq 'Camera'}.FriendlyName).ForEach{
    powershell -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ". $PSScriptRoot\ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -show_video_device_dialog true -i video='$PSItem'"
}
```

---

Oh and I used **ffmpeg-git-essentials** *(version: 2021-09-30-git-3ee4502753*) from [gyan.dev](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/).

And yes, you can list the camera devices using **ffmpeg** too, but you'll have to do some string manipulation in order to use its values in a loop.

```winbatch
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy -hide_banner
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking for this answer as well and not finding any Open Source implementation I went on a wrote one:

https://github.com/PatBQc/SeriousWebcamSettings

Serious Webcam Settings Window example available on GitHub Open source repository:
[image: Serious Webcam Settings Window exemple available on Github Open source repository]