How can I adjust settings of my Logitech Brio webcam on Win 10 without using software like OBS or LogiTune?
I want to be able to change the tilt, focus, etc.
LogiTune is super buggy, and OBS is overkill.
Is there a built-in way on Windows 10 (command line is fine but not ideal)?
P.S. Here are the controls within OBS:

Here is LogiTune:


OBS is never an overkill, but it doesn't allow you to change such parameters of camera in the 1st place.

@Destroy666 I disagree on both points. I updated my question to show the OBS controls.

It's not an OBS window as it can be clearly seen by different styling. It asks Windows to open the configuration for the device.

@Destroy666 Thanks for linking to https://superuser.com/a/1544770/74576. Very cool.

No, Windows does not contain built-in methods to control these aspects of a Logitech Brio camera.

OBS exposes settings like LogiTune even though Logitech didn't make OBS. How does OBS get access to let me change those settings? It seems like Windows exposed them. Thanks.

It's an API likely. Windows doesn't have much of anything to do with that except providing an environment to host this.

ok, thanks. I now see this answer about mice https://superuser.com/a/1701645/74576 and it makes me want to look for simple LogiTune alternatives that are more reliable.

You'll want to make sure to ask that question over on our SoftwareRecs sister site and not here.
